# C: Punteros. Conversión a puntero desde un entero de tamaño diferente

Tags: c

Necesito ayuda, estoy tratando de crear una función que recibe una ruta de fichero, localice las barras, y extraiga el nombre del mismo.

Para ello, estoy empleando la función strcmp(s1,s2), para conocer si el actual carácter es barra o no.

La cuestión es que al compilar: "Conversión a puntero desde un entero de tamaño diferente". en la línea 12:

```
if(strcmp((char*)*ruta_fue,"/")==0)
```

Entonces no sé que significa.

Mi primera versión fue:

```
if(strcmp((*ruta_fue,"/")==0)
```

pero el compilador: El paso del argumento 1 a strcmp crea un puntero desde un entero sin una conversión.

La cuestión es: ¿Cómo accedo al carácter actual desde un puntero de char*?

El programa es:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


char* nombreFichero(char* ruta_fue){
char* nombre = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(ruta_fue));
char* origen = nombre;
int i;
for(i=0;i<strlen(ruta_fue);i++){

if(strcmp((char*)*ruta_fue,"/")==0){
    if(i!=strlen(ruta_fue)-1){
        free(nombre);
        nombre = origen;
        ruta_fue++;
    }
}else{
    *nombre=*ruta_fue;
    nombre++;
    ruta_fue++;
}
}
nombre=origen;
return nombre;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
char * ruta;
if(argc!=2){
printf("Error el uso es: nombreFichero ruta\n");
return -1;
}
ruta =(char*) argv[1];
printf("El nombre del fichero es: %s\n",nombreFichero(ruta));
}
```

También estaría agradecido si alguien me explica cómo insertar código de manera sencilla, porque creo que espaciar cada línea con 4 espacios no es lo ideal.

Gracias.

Comment: enoy, para indentar el código depende de que IDE usas ?

Answer (score 1):

`*ruta_fue*` es de tipo `char` (que es lo que requiere `strcmp`) y tú le pasas `(char *)*ruta_fue`, es decir:

**1-** `ruta_fue` contiene la dirección de la cadena, pongamos que es
   `0x123456`.

**2-** Con `*ruta_fue` obtienes el `char` almacenado en la posición 0 de la
    cadena. Pongamos que es `a`.

**3-** Con `(char *)*ruta_fue` estás usando el `char` de la posición 0 de la
    cadena como dirección de una cadena, es decir le estás pasando a
    `strcmp` una cadena almacenada en `0x40` (el valor ASCII de `a``). Sobra
    decir que obtendrás basura o un error de segmentación.

Lo que tú quieres es simplemente comparar si dos caracteres son iguales: `ruta_fue[0] == '/'`